# Change view properties EventAggregator Aurelia

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

```
import {inject, bindable, customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@customElement('add-company-modal')
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class AddCompanyModal {
    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    attached() {
        console.log('attached add company modal');

        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('add-company-modal-toggle', open => {
            console.log('getting hit');
            if (open) this.open();
            else this.close();
        });
    }

    open() {
        this.activate = true;
    }

    close() {
        this.activate = false;
    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? Basically I have another view model which is publishing events. the console log is getting read out. The idea is that `activate` is bound to a `class`:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop ${activate ? 'modal-show' : ''}" click.trigger="close()">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-title">
            <h1>Add Company <span class="modal-close">x</span></h1>    
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modal-no-footer">
            <add-company>

            </add-company>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is wrapped in a `template`. However, this doesn't show at all. It works if I have a `bindable` property, but only when you click open on the other vm. When you close the modal you can't reopen it again, hence why I am using the event aggregator.

So the `console.log` is getting hit, I know that I have set up the event aggregation correctly, I just have a feeling that the framework isn't picking this up. I know if this was angular then it could be outside the digest cycle but I know aurelia doesn't work like that.

### Reproduction

I've created a small repo to reproduce the issues on my [Github](https://github.com/no1melman/ModalRepro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the value coming through to the subscribe callback was always `false`.

It was an error else where in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`activate` might sound better as `activated` or `isActivated`.

Just FYI there is a life-cycle method the router will call that is named `activate` so just trying to let you know of that possible collision.

If that doesn't help the next step for me would be to log the value of `open` inside the subscribe event.  I would also verify that it's not failing with a `method undefined error` or anything.

Last, I personally like to define the properties either on the class or in the constructor.  It's possible that you are binding to `undefined` so it doesn't catch the value change.

```
export class AddCompanyModal {
    isActivated = false;
    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    attached() {
        console.log('attached add company modal');
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('add-company-modal-toggle', open => {
            console.log('getting hit');
            if (open) this.open();
            else this.close();
        });
    }

    open() {
        this.isActivated = true;
    }

    close() {
        this.isActivated = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah so as I said, all my console logs are getting hit. I will create the class member variable and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Nope, so that change didn't make a difference. Should this work as is? I did try with `@bindable activate` and that worked till the vm trying to change it's value a second time when it failed.

Comment: I'm getting no errors in the console about `method undefined error`

Comment: I've added a [github](https://github.com/no1melman/ModalRepro) link to a reproduction of the issue.